# Is it possible to get a Haskell executable to return a value to a bash script that calls it?

Tags: bash, haskell

**I have a bash script that calls a Haskell executable, is it possible to get that Haskell exe to return a value such that it can be stored as a bash variable?**

For example, say I have the two files: `haskellFile.hs` and `BashScript`.

(1) I compile the haskell file like so `ghc -o exe haskellFile.hs`

(2) In my `BashScript` it calls the exe like so `./exe arg1 arg2`

Currently I have my haskell file print to output, but I'd like it to return a value so I could do  something like `bashVar = ./exe arg1 arg2`

This is basically what my haskell file looks like at the moment:

```
main :: IO()
main = do (arg1:arg2:_) <- getArgs
    let returnValue = someFunction arg1 arg2
    print $ returnValue -- But I want it to return a value
```

Comment: If the Haskell prints to `stdout` then `bashVar=$(./exe arg1 arg2)` note no spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "return a value"? Bash doesn't have a concept of "return values" for commands, so no, you cannot "return a value" because the whole concept of "returning" doesn't exist. There are two ways that a command can communicate with the outside world: writing to a file (and that includes stdout, stderr, pipes, sockets, etc.) and specifically for communicating success or failure to the calling command (usually the shell): exit codes. So, printing to stdout would be the correct way, but you explicitly exclude that, so there is no way.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, there are at least two other ways, which are quite irrelevant: it can send a signal to another process and it can write to shared memory.

Comment: Point being, the asker seems unclear about the basic mechanisms of processes and how shell scripts can (and can not) orchestrate processes.  If the asker can clarify, even if that clarification is asking for OS concept details, then it would help.

Comment: `bash` does have a concept of return value for commands, but it's an integer (possibly quite small). From the manual: ["The return value of a simple command is its exit status, or 128+n if the command is terminated by signal n."](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html#Simple-Commands) This is exit status is the `exitWith` argument. That said, it's not read as in this question. Consider [`bashStr="$(command)"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) or `command ; bashInt=$?`.

Answer (score 5):

Programs can send information to a shell through these channels:

1. The exit code, a number from 0-255. See [`exitWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html#v:exitWith).
2. File descriptors, a collection of independent sequences of bytes. The most commonly used are stdout and stderr. (Under normal circumstances, fd 0 (stdin) is read-only, and so is not usually a way for programs to send information to the shell.) Use e.g. `putStr`/`putStrLn`/`print` to send information to stdout, and `hPutStr`/`hPutStrLn`/`hPrint` with [`stderr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:stderr) to send information to stderr. Communicating on other fds is more involved; if you're interested, say so and I can write a bit more about this.
3. The file system. (I assume you know the basics of communicating with this medium.)

These channels can always be used to send information shell-ward (though of course whatever shell script you're writing is free to ignore any information communicated that way!). Additionally, other channels can be set up by the shell before invoking the program; e.g. named pipes, sockets, dbus, shared memory, ...